# Loan calculator task - how to find monthly payment by loan term?

Tags: algorithm, math

Among the programming problems which I am to test for correctness, I encountered the following, for which I fear I do not know the good solution.

http://codeabbey.com/index/task_view/mortgage-calculator

Shortly: here is a loan of given size `P` which is increased monthly by interest rate `R% / 12` and from which client's monthly payment `M` is then subtracted. Over `L` months debt is decreased to zero (i.e. client paid it out).

It looks that given `P`, `M` and `R` I can easily calculate `L` with simple loop. But here is the reverse task - I am to find the monthly payment `M` by given loan term `L` along  with `P` and `R`.

I think that perhaps I can use binary search to test different variants of `M` and repeatedly calculating `L` for them... But I am not sure if this would be proper - and I wonder that probably there exist some straight mathematical solution which I could not find?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for "loan formula monthly payment." Here's a site that has the loan formula, and an example: http://www.1728.org/loanform.htm. (They throw in several ads for good measure.) There's also "Mortgage calculator" at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator , which has the formula for M that you're looking for (they call it c).

Comment: Thanks a lot - with help of your comment I now can understand the answer below completely. Very stupid I did not find the wiki article. However I even could not imagine it could be done without iterations...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate this in constant time.

```
Rm = R / 12

M = P * Rm / ((1 - (1 + Rm)^(-L)))
```

Where `^` stands for exponentiation. For example:

```
P = 1000
R = 24% = 0.24
Rm = 0.24 / 12 = 0.02
L = 5 months

M = 1000 * 0.02 / (1 - 1.02^(-5))
M = 212.16
```

Let's see if it works:

```
P0 = 1000
P1 = 1020 // interest
P1' = 807,84 // rate paid, end of first month
P2 = 823,9968
P2' = 611,8368 // after second month
P3 = 624,073536
P3' = 411,913536 // after third month
P4 = 420,15180672
P4' = 207,99180672 // after fourth month
P5 = 212,1516428544
```

And here you pay it off completely after the fifth month. The number doesn't match 100% due to rounding. You would according to the link round M to 213. However you end up rounding it, round it *up*, not *down*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a problem understanding the formula, but with the help of the links in the comment above I think I can get the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with it today.
I think they wanted the task without formulas. Like a gearing. For educational purpose.
It was hard to me too. So, after inspiration in previous Binary Search equation problem, finally I found a way.

```
def incrMontant(montant,interest,months,payment=0):
while months:
    increment = montant * (interest/100) /12
    montant += increment
    montant -= payment   #this trick call other function.
    months-=1
return montant

def payment(montant,interest,months):
pay = 0
while incrMontant(montant,interest,months,pay) > 0:
    pay += 1
return pay

montant, interest, months = (int(x) for x in input().split())
print(payment(montant,interest,months))
```